# CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x27t6) Port not available. Exiting... in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-iedriver

I am getting the below errors when running Selenium script. Recently I did setup Selenium grid and started noticing after that. I stopped the Hub and restarted the system also but still having same issue. Also tried with latest Chrome and IE Drivers.

Chrome Error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b) on port 11055
Only local connections are allowed.
[0.147][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726)
[0.147][SEVERE]: CreatePlatformSocket() returned an error: An invalid argument was supplied. (0x27t6) Port not available. Exiting...
```

IE Error:

```
Failed to start the server with: port = '2305', host = '', log level = '', log file = '', whitelisted ips = ''
```

Comment: There might be some other issues here, how are you creating the drivers in your code?

Comment: DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities); This was working fine before without having any issues.

Comment: Is the `webdriver.chrome.driver` property set correctly and referencing the correct `chromedriver` on the needed machines for your grid? Other than that, I have seen some issues with selenium grid at a company where our devops team locked things up way too tightly. If that's the case you might try setting up a hub and a node on your local machine first to see if you run into these problems

Comment: I am not using the grid at all now. I have written separate functions for grid/non-grid options. Yes, I am referring to the correct and latest chromdriver in the properties as shown in the Chrome Error stack.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved now after I moved the driver executables from network driver to local drive. I guess some policies changed in our company so stopped working before.